# Marshaling C++ jagged array gives "Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination" error

Tags: c++, interop

This is my C++ definition:

```
typedef struct _DRIVER_VERSION
{
DWORD DriverNum;
CHAR Version[16][16];
} DRIVER_INFO, *PDRIVER_INFO;
```

And thsi is my C# interop code:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct Version16
{
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
    public string VerInfo;
}


/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct _DRIVER_VERSION
{
    public System.UInt32 DriverNum;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
    public Version16 Version16;

}

    public static class InstallDeviceClass
{
    [DllImport(@"driver.dll")]
    public static extern SResultEnum s4drv_GetDriverInfo(ref _DRIVER_VERSION pDrvInfo);
}

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _DRIVER_VERSION version=new _DRIVER_VERSION();
        var s4Res = InstallDeviceClass.s4drv_GetDriverInfo(ref version);
    }
```

However, when I run the code, I will get

> $exception    {"Cannot marshal field 'Version16' of type
>   '_DRIVER_VERSION': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (this
>   value type must be paired with Struct).":""}  System.TypeLoadException

Any reason why is this happening, and how to fix this?

Comment: @xanatos, and so?

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for your tip, I've solved the problem. Would you like to make your comment into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is

```
/// </summary>
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct _DRIVER_VERSION
{
    public System.UInt32 DriverNum;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
    public Version16[] Version16;

}
```

The `Version16` is should be an array, not a field